# Ingresar datos a excel sin especificar la celda desde Python

Tags: python, excel

Quisiera saber si hay un código de python donde, al ingresar datos, se preestablescan las columnas donde se van a grabar, pero sin necesidad de ingresar la fila.

Por ponerlo así, digamos que establecí las celdas A1, B1, C1 y D1, donde voy a especificar los datos que van a ir debajo, y sin importar si se repiten o no, se puedan ingresar datos continuamente sin estar especificando la fila de la celda.

Es que voy a crear un registro de asistencia en excel mediante Python y Arduino.

[image: Presentación Grafica]

Comment: O bien guardas en una variable global cuántas filas has escrito o bien lees el documento Excel hasta encontrar una fila vacía para escribir en ella.